# limsup convergence and series with positive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Construct an example for which $a_{n}\ge 0$ and $limsup_{n}na_{n}=\infty$ and yet $\sum_{n}a_{n}$ is convergent.

I found and understood the answer on this website for the case $limsup_{n}na_{n}>0$. But infinity is more extreme and I could not find an exact idea.
I am very sorry for forgetting the most basic terms in the previous version of this question

Answer (score 2):

For the old version:

There is no such sequence. If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $a_n \to 0$. Any convergent sequence is bounded so $\lim \sup a_n <\infty$.

For the revised version of the question take $a_n=\frac  1{\sqrt n}$ if $n=m^{4}$ for some, $m$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Geetha. I am sorry for forgetting n.

Comment: @mathsandchess I have edited my answer.